# .join causing an error that says it is not a function

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have this in the firestore where "1" is a map with `selected`. If it exist, it won't cause any error. But if it does not exist, it says that `.join` is not a function.

```
user[1]?.selected?.join(", ")
```

This is what it looks like in firestore

[image]

Will this be fine, I've made a workaround on this one?

```
{user[1]?.selected ? (
                          <>
                            {" "}
                            <ListItemText
                              primary={user[1]?.selected.join(", ")}
                            />
                          </>
                        ) : (
                          <></>
                        )}
```

Comment: What's the exact error message? I think everything here depends on what you mean precisely by "if it exists"  and by "is not a method". Because there are many ways not to exist and many ways not to be a function. I know, I'm not one.

Comment: What's the problem? If it doesn't exist you can't call a function on it.

Comment: @djfm I've posted what it looks like in the firestore

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is because - even if it exists, it's not an Array.
Has to be an Array in order to use the Array.prototype.join()

```js
const user = {
  1: {selected: [1, 2, 4]},
  2: {},
  3: {selected: "test this"},  // << Uncaught TypeError
};

console.log( user[1]?.selected?.join(", ") ); // "1, 2, 4"
console.log( user[2]?.selected?.join(", ") ); // undefined
console.log( user[3]?.selected?.join(", ") ); // Uncaught TypeError
```

so, `Uncaught TypeError` because you cannot use `.join()` on String primitive

Comment: is there some way I could display the data where it will separate each of the values? Without the `.join`, it would not display any error but the data will display where each of the words does not have any spaces, something like this - `CarsBooksChairs`

Comment: @RavenousRed please show me an example of the `selected` property **value**.

Comment: I've posted what it looks like in firestore

Comment: @RavenousRed LOL, so it's an Array I suppose? `user[1]?.selected?.join(", ") || ""` will fallback to an Empty string instead of showing `undefined`.

Comment: I forgot to mention that `selected` was initially a string, then when a user submits the 2nd time like adding another value on `selected`  it becomes an array. If it is not an array, that's where the `join` causes an error